# How to create function to get one object or null?

Tags: java

I am newbie in Java. How to create function to get one object or null?

I have simple class:

```
public class Auto {
    Auto (String text) {

    }
}
```

And other class I would like to have method onAuto:

```
public class AutoSearch {
    public Auto oneAuto()
    {
        //operations
        String text = getOperations();
        if (text) {
            Auto auto = new Auto(text);
           return auto;
        } else {
           return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But this not working, because method have to return object Auto.

What if I can't create object Auto in this method? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see how `if (String)` is supposed to work

Comment: Indeed - your return statements look fine, but the `if` condition isn't. It would help if you'd be clearer about what "not working" means - what *exact* error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to verify if text exists in order to create an `Auto` object, am I correct?

```
public class AutoSearch {

    public Auto oneAuto() {

        String text = getOperations();

        if (text != null) {
            return new Auto(text);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

You can do this in a more compact way too, using the ternary operator:

```
public class AutoSearch {

    public Auto oneAuto() {
        return text != null ? new Auto(text) : null;
    }

}
```

Yet, in Java the expression inside an `if` statement MUST resolve to an boolean (true or false). You seems to think that Java works like Javascript, and its definitely not the case. Java and Javascript have only the name in common.

As davidxxx said, probably you will need to define the `Auto` constructor as public.

Answer (score 0):

1)    `if (text)` is not a boolean expression. 
It cannot compile. But `if (text != null)` can.

2)You declared the `Auto` constructor with a package private access modifier.
It means that `AutoSearch` has to be in the same package as `Auto` to be able to invoke this constructor.
Or else change the `Auto` constructor to `public` :

```
public Auto (String text) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the **text** is empty or not. if it is empty return null and if it have content, then return the **Object**

```
 if("".equals(text) || text == null){
          return null;
 } else {
         return auto
 }
```